# 0ad backport on Trusty (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, games, backport

Is there possibility to upgrade 0ad from Trusty backports to 0.0.16 version? I can see that in backports there is 0.0.16 version http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/games/0ad . But after update and upgrade nothing happens. I selected trusty - backports repo. Thanks!

Comment: What is the version you are using right now?

Comment: Version: 0.0.15+dfsg-3